# Printing string array elements c++

Tags: c++

Trying to print an element from my array of strings. Marked comment where error is.

Getting the errors:

1. ```
   IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are: 
   std::ostream << const std::string
   ```
2. ```
   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
   of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
   ```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int day = 5, year = 2015;


    const string months[13] = { 0, "January", "February", "March", "April", 
                               "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                              "October", "November", "December" };

    cout << months[5] << " " << day << ", " << year << endl;  //the first << is the issue
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't `#include <string>`, you were lucky enough that some parts of `<string>` were found in `<iostream>` so you could declare `months`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another problem occurs after I added string. I get debug assertion failed and have to abort. Any idea why this happens?